# wide table using MDPI template

Tags: pdftex, mdpi

I am using MDPI latex template [here](https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/mdpi-article-template/fcpwsspfzsph). I have a wide table that should span the whole width.

To reproduce the problem, please use this MWE. The MWE code must be executed inside mdpi template e.g. overleaf

```
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi} 


% MDPI internal commands
\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{1}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{0}
\pubyear{2021}
\copyrightyear{2020}
\datereceived{} 
\dateaccepted{} 
\datepublished{} 
\hreflink{https://doi.org/} % If needed use \linebreak

% Full title of the paper (Capitalized)
\Title{Title}

% MDPI internal command: Title for citation in the left column
\TitleCitation{Title}

% Author Orchid ID: enter ID or remove command
\newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0000-0000-000X} % Add \orcidA{} behind the author's name
%\newcommand{\orcidauthorB}{0000-0000-0000-000X} % Add \orcidB{} behind the author's name

% Authors, for the paper (add full first names)
\Author{Firstname Lastname $^{1,\dagger,\ddagger}$\orcidA{}, Firstname Lastname $^{1,\ddagger}$ and Firstname Lastname $^{2,}$*}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for metadata in PDF
\AuthorNames{Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname and Firstname Lastname}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for citation in the left column
\AuthorCitation{Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.}
% If this is a Chicago style journal: Lastname, Firstname, Firstname Lastname, and Firstname Lastname.

% Affiliations / Addresses (Add [1] after \address if there is only one affiliation.)
\address{%
$^{1}$ \quad Affiliation 1; e-mail@e-mail.com\\
$^{2}$ \quad Affiliation 2; e-mail@e-mail.com}

% Contact information of the corresponding author
\corres{Correspondence: e-mail@e-mail.com; Tel.: (optional; include country code; if there are multiple corresponding authors, add author initials) +xx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx (F.L.)}

% Current address and/or shared authorship
\firstnote{Current address: Affiliation 3} 
\secondnote{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\abstract{}

% Keywords
\keyword{keyword 1; keyword 2; keyword 3 (List three to ten pertinent keywords specific to the article; yet reasonably common within the subject discipline.)} 


\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{section}{-1} %% Remove this when starting to work on the template.

\section{Introduction}

\begin{specialtable}[H]
\widefigure
\caption{Summary of various datasets including free-view datasets, crowd-surveillance view and drone-view} 
\label{table:table2}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c}
\toprule
Name                & Year & Attributes                      & Avg. Resolution & No. samples & No. instances & Avg. count \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Free view datasets}                                                                                  \\ \midrule
NWPU-Crowd \cite{gao2020nwpu}          & 2020 & Congested, Localization         & 2191x3209       & 5,109       & 2,133,375     & 418        \\ \midrule
JHU-CROWD++ \cite{sindagi2019pushing}        & 2020 & Congested                       & 1430x910        & 4,372       & 1,515,005     & 346        \\ \midrule
JHU-CROWD++ \cite{Idrees2018CompositionLF}         & 2018 & Congested                       & 2013x2902       & 1,535       & 1,251,642     & 815        \\ \midrule
ShanghaiTech Part A \cite{liu2018ano_pred}  & 2016 & Congested                     & 589x868         & 482         & 241,677       & 501        \\ \midrule
UCF\_CC\_50 \cite{6619173}  & 2013 & Congested                      & 2101x2888       & 50          & 241,677       & 1,279      \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{specialtable}
\end{document}
```

I usualy use `\begin{table*}` and It is working fine, I am wondering what is the benefit or the goal of introducing new  command like `specialtable`, `parcol`, ....

but the table is still shifted at right

Note that in the IEEE template, everything is working fine by using

```
\begin{table*}
....
\end{table*}
```

So the problem is related to MDPI internal command such as `\specialtable`

[image]

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question.

Comment: @leandriis, it is done

Comment: @BetterEnglish, no it is not. You provide  only code sniped, not an MWE (Minimal Working Example), which is complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please extend your code fragment accordingly.

Comment: @Zarko, the template needs  many including files that exists in Definitions folder to be executed, that why I propose to download and copy paste the code. It is much more simple. If you know anyway to upload all these files, please share it

Comment: @Zarko, I included a complete code sample but we still need to execute that inside MDPI template. Is it what you need ?

Comment: MDPI template is complex. You need to follow their instructions (in the `template.tex`) to the letter. I tried to give a solution below... Do not worry too much about the rendering of the article perfectly, they will not typeset it with LaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Update, Nov 1, 2022***

The template got quite better, meanwhile; Now the "wide" figures are a matter of putting them into an `adjustwidth` environment and using the `\fulllength` size:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-\extralength}{0cm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.95\fulllength]{panoramic_figure}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \caption{This figure will be full-page.\label{fig:panoramic}}
\end{figure}
```

***Original answer (dec 2021)***

The problem here is that the MDPI template is, well, strange. To insert a wide figure you have to do the following dance (taken from the file `template.tex` in the distribution):

```latex
\end{paracol}
% Example of a figure that spans the whole page width (the commands \widefigure and \begin{paracol}{2}, \linenumbers, and\switchcolumn need to be present). The same concept works for tables, too.
\begin{figure}[H]
\widefigure
\includegraphics[width=15 cm]{Figs/circuit-2}
\caption{This is a wide figure with the full prototype.\label{fig:my-main-fig}}
\end{figure}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\linenumbers
\switchcolumn
```

...and the `\end{paracol}` etc parts are *mandatory*. The template issue a `\begin{paracol}{2}` at the `\begin{document}` command (that you *have to close manually* before the reference section), so to insert a wide figure, you have to stop the `paracol`, insert the figure (positioning it manually), and then restart the environment.

I imagine that changing `figure` for `table` (or `specialtable`, as suggested in the template --- test it) and then putting there a `tabularx` spanning the whole `\linewidth` will give you the result you want.

I would have organized the template in a completely different way. In the end, it's a one-column template with a lot of space for marginpars at the left, space that has to disappear when starting the references. It's not an easy template to reproduce in LaTeX, but I think that the solution used by MDPI is at least too fragile.

Comment: Calling MDPI template "strange" is such a generous euphemism!

Answer (score 1):

I guess, that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

Just some fragment, how to set your table. Your document preamble should contend:

```
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

and table body:

```
%\caption{Summary of various datasets including free-view datasets, crowd-surveillance view and drone-view}
\label{table:table2}
    \sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,
             group-separator={,},
             }
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l c L 
                             S[table-format=4.0,product-symbol = {{\times}}]
                             S[table-format=4.0] 
                             S[table-format=7.0]
                             S[table-format=4.0] @{}}
    \toprule
Name    
    &   Year  
        &   Attributes    
            &   {\makecell{Average\\ Resolution}}
                &   {\makecell{No. \\ samples}}
                    &   {\makecell{No.\\ instances}} 
                        &   {\makecell{Average\\ count}}  \\ 
    \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Free view datasets}                                                                                  \\ \midrule
NWPU-Crowd \cite{gao2020nwpu}
    &   2020 
        &   Congested, Localization   
            &   \numproduct{2191x3209} 
                &   5 109 
                    &   2 133 375 
                        &   418         \\ 
    \addlinespace
JHU-CROWD++ \cite{sindagi2019pushing}        
    &   2020 
        &   Congested 
            &   \numproduct{1430x910}\hphantom{,0}
                &   4 372       
                    &   1 515 005     
                            &   346     \\ 
    \addlinespace
JHU-CROWD++ \cite{Idrees2018CompositionLF}         
    &   2018 
        &   Congested      
            &   \numproduct{2013x2902} 
                &   1 535  
                    &   1 251 642 
                        &   815        \\ 
    \addlinespace
ShanghaiTech Part A \cite{liu2018ano_pred}  
    &   2016 
        & Congested 
            &   \numproduct{589x868} 
                &   482 
                    &   241 677 
                        &   501         \\ 
    \addlinespace
UCF\_CC\_50 \cite{6619173}  
    &   2013 
        &   Congested
            &   \numproduct{2101x2888}       
                &   50
                    &   241 677
                        &   1 279      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

You need to insert this table code fragment to your place, where is your code fragment. If you like to have a MWE with your table, you need first to provide in your question a MWE, which we can test in our Overleaf accounts, instead just code fragment.

Comment: The problem is that the MDPI template body is really inside a `paracol` environment, and so to have a wide table you have to stop it, flush, insert the table and restart the environment. It's a bit of mess, yes...

Comment: I have been using Latex since 2009, never see this degree of 'stupidity'! Replace something simple and working very well with something so complicated! Waste of time

Comment: I think it's more complex than that, @BetterEnglish. LaTeX is not really suited for formats where page margins change mid-page, and they tried to implement that the best they could. Inserting full-page inserts (figures it tables) in the middle of the page is not trivial (consider that plain LaTeX, and the IEEE template, when in two columns mode, admits wide figures/tables *only on the top of the page*!). So do not blame them too much; probably the task is next to impossible.

Comment: @Rmano, I agree with you. I don't know how he inserted the table into the document, so I asked him to insert MWE into the his question. Unfortunately, he refuse this (now he is added, but for my answer is to late), rather he blame my solution as stupid. Is it really that stupid? In my opinion, the result is much better than given by his fragment of the table.

Comment: @Zarko I think that the "stupid" was directed to the authors of the template, which is frankly quite complex to use --- although the problem itself is not easy to solve, as I tried to explain above. Your table is perfect to be put inside the snippet I (well, MDPI author) reported in my answer!

Comment: @Rmano, thank you very much. I apology to  BetterEnglish, If I accuse doe to my wrong understanding of his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you get here looking for how to use wide tables in the MDPI LYX template, just do not overlook that in lyx there a command: **\widetable** that could be used in ERL at the begining of the table to produce the wide table. There is another command \widefigure to do the same for figures and it is used in the template.