# Landscape appendix on MDPI template

Tags: tables, overleaf, landscape, mdpi

I am trying to write an article using the MDPI template, in Overleaf. I managed to learn and adapt most issues I had using this template, but I am having some problems adding a large table on the appendix.
I am using the following code, corresponding to the last part of the template:

```
%% Optional
\appendixtitles{yes} % Leave argument "no" if all appendix headings stay EMPTY (then no dot is printed after "Appendix A"). If the appendix sections contain a heading then change the argument to "yes".
\appendixstart
\appendix
\begin{landscape}
\section{Simulation Results}

\begin{specialtable}[H]
    \caption{Results and errors for displacements and membrane thickness - Patient 1}
    \begin{tabular} {M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M}
        (TABULAR 1)
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:T_TwoModelsPat1}
\end{specialtable}

\begin{specialtable}[H]
        \caption{Results and errors for displacements and membrane thickness  - Patient 2}
        \begin{tabular} {M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M|M}
            (TABULAR 2)
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:T_TwoModelsPat2}
\end{specialtable}
\end{landscape}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

However, this is resulting in this format:
[image: Result]
Which is not what I want. If possible, I want the header to stay on the 'top' of the page, and for the tables to be spread horizontally. Like this example, from a random MDPI article:
[image: Desired table]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Wild guess: in MDPI template there is a mandatory `\end{paracol}` before the wide figures, and a `\paracol...` after. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606032/38080 maybe you have to do the same for tables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Rmano. It kinda works!! I added \end{paracol} before the \appendixtitles{yes} and \begin{paracol} after \end{landscape}. The tables rotate nicely. The only problem remaining is the head, which is still sideways, but I can work with that. I'll keep the thread open to see if anyone can figure out how to fix the header.

Comment: We could help more if you are able to prepare a small, compilable and complete example...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about appendix, but as for the table, I would have made it here on this [site](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) (as for me it is really useful and encreace coding scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Use `\startlandscape` and `\finishlandscape`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).