# How can I replicate the format of this research paper?

Tags: floats, header-footer, margins, two-column

I've found a paper in the format of which I would like to copy and use for my own writing. I'd ike to know which packages I need or basic types of commands I might need to reproduce it. The elements are shown below but the main points are:

- Single column for page 1
- Large space on the left of page 1 for acknowledgements
- Double columns from page 2 onwards
- Header and footer for journal details
- Large figures are spaced in single-column format

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is really similar to the MDPI template. In https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606008/wide-table-using-mdpi-template/606032?noredirect=1#comment1559430_606032 you can find a link. It's not an exemplary template, mind you, but it can be used in a pinch (and maybe made better)

Comment: That looks similar indeed. But would I be able to change the citation style to APA? So that I can use the /citep and /citet commands and have in-text citations appear the way I want them to?

Comment: You mention "for [your] own writings." Is this ultimately for submissions to a journal?

Comment: Yes it is, but not to this journal. I just liked the format and thought it would be a useful base template. I want to edit it to my own liking or adapt it for submission to other journals, based on which ones accept my writing.

Answer (score 1):

here you'll find the right latex template from the journal's site itself
https://www.frontiersin.org/design/zip/Frontiers_LaTeX_Templates.zip